# Should I inform my internship that I have received a job offer from a different company?

Tags: professionalism, job-offer, internship

I'm quickly coming to the end of my senior year of college. I'm currently working at an internship in my field. I don't particularly like this internship - its not the subject in my field that I would like to make a life in, and I feel like they don't really trust me to do the job they hired me for (but they haven't really given me any training on how to do it).

This week I got a job offer from a different company. A job that is in the subject matter I want to make my life in, a job that offers better compensation than I think my internship could offer, a job that has much more opportunity for future growth. Unless my internship offers me **significantly** more compensation, I would accept this job offer in a heartbeat.

How do I tell my internship? Do I inform them that I have *accepted* an offer (an go ahead and accept the job offer), or that I have *received* an offer so that they have the option of making their own offer?

Comment: Under what terms did you accept the internship (ie was it for a fixed number of months?) Has the intern employer offered a full time position? Is the new position for another internship, or a "real" job? Is it dependent on your finishing your senior year? Have you received a formal offer, or just had discussions about an offer?

Comment: The other position is a "real" job, for which I have received a formal written offer. With the internship I never really had a formal length or terms. Its a smaller company (13 people, including the upper management), and I have received mixed signals about whether I will even be offered a full position. The CTO talks like I'll get an offer, but the project manager has made some comments to me that make me think otherwise (but I also have a habit of catastrophic thinking and extrapolation, so take that with a grain of salt).

Comment: @MariaLuna This sounds like a no-brainer.

Comment: @dfundako The more I put it into words, yeah it does.

Comment: Maria - you may want to clarify your last paragraph. Are you simply asking how to inform your current employer of a decision you've already made, or are you asking for help on how to make the decision of which employer to work for? (and possibly how to negotiate?)

Comment: @dwizum In a way, both. I was having trouble finding information regarding how to handle receiving a job offer while at an internship, but now that I've been talking through the situation in some of the other comments, I see that I'm probably just going to have to figure out how to inform my internship of the decision.

Comment: Internships are meant to be for training and NOT  just a "job" and you don't have to join as an employee the place you last interned at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question, you would keep your current position even though you don't like it and it is not in your field of interest just because they matched salary/pay?

Next, if you decide this new opportunity is right for you, don't say anything until you formally accept and get your offer/particulars in writing with a start date. Then schedule a meeting with your advisor/boss/supervisor and say:

> "Hey boss, I have received a job offer from another company and I have
>   accepted it. I feel this new role is a great opportunity and after
>   giving it much consideration, I can't pass it up. I wanted to tell you
>   in person and also let you know how much I appreciate everything you
>   have done for me in this internship. My last day will be YYYY-MM-DD
>   and I'll make sure to have everything wrapped up or ready to
>   transition by that day. If there is anything else that I can assist with between now and then, please let me know."

If you are even slightly interested in working for the company that your internship is through, be prepared to throw a number at them if they ask what it will take to convert you to a full time employee.

> "Hey Boss. I am flattered that you want to keep me on staff and have
>   me as a full time employee. In order for me to seriously consider the
>   offer, I would require XX/hr or YY per year."

If not interested at all,

> "Hey Boss. I am flattered that you want to keep me on staff and have me be a full time employee, but I unfortunately have to decline. I feel this new opportunity is more aligned with my career and growth goals. If I come across anyone in my network that seems like they would be a good fit for a role here, I will be sure to send them your way.

Comment: They would have to exceed the salary offered by the other company - but I don't think my internship company even has the means to exceed the other company.

Comment: @MariaLuna They might surprise you and have the means to do it. Be prepared with a number and be prepared personally as to which position is best for you.

Comment: @MariaLuna Another thing to consider is your 3-5 year plan. A couple thousand dollars more per year right out of college sounds great, but if the other role could put you on a path to make 30-40,000 more per year due to growth opportunities, then that might be the smarter route.

Answer (score 0):

If this get marked as a duplicate I will delete my answer.

I would not make it sound like a threat.  My thought is to tell them you are nearing graduation and need to make plans.  Ask them if they intend to make you an offer. If they stall then just take the other offer.

Comment: I think with this approach, they would take weeks to get back to him.

Comment: @SandraK Then my advice is to just take the other offer.   If they are excited about keeping him they should tell him.

Comment: @paparazzo I think what Sandra meant is that it might take weeks because they have to get approval, budget, etc. They might say, "hey look we want you but first we have to get the budget." Ultimately the OP might have to say goodbye, I can't wait that long on a promise.

Comment: @Dan It is still my answer.  OP cannot risk a good thing if they are not ready to pull the trigger.